¿En filamentphp, como llenar los campos de un formulario con los datos del perfil del usuario login?
Estoy trabajando con Filamentphp, y he creado un recurso "Informe". Al momento de crear un Informe deseo cargar automáticamente datos del usuario Logueado al formulario.
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('employee_name')
          ->label('Elaborado por:')
          ->default(aquí cargar el nombre del usuario logueado que se encuentra en la tabla profile)
          ->disabled()
          ->dehydrated(),

Pero en realidad lo que quiero guardar es el nombre del usario que se encuentra en una talba 'Profile' relacionada por el user_id.
A su vez necesito hacer lo mismo pero de la tabla 'departments'
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('department')
          ->label('Agencia')
          ->default(aquí cargar el nombre del departamento del usuario logueado que se encuentra en la tabla deparments)
          ->disabled()
          ->dehydrated(),

ya tengo mis modelos con sus relaciones listas.
Modelo User
public function profile() 
{
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); 
}

Modelo Department
public function profile(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
}

Modelo Profile
public function department()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

